# How to check additional field during login in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to check additional field during login in Laravel?

Now it works from the box and accepts email and password. How to check additionally status parameter when user log in?

I use this `LoginController`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   use AuthenticatesUsers;
}
```

I tried this in LoginController:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $credentials['status'] = 1;

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
    }
```

But Laravel ignores this method `authenticate().`

if to remove `use AuthenticatesUsers;` it becomes alive, but then does not work logout, login page.

Comment: are you want to attach another parameter when user wants to login ? like email , password and user type ?

Comment: please check the right answer as your solution as stackoverflow policy. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can add another field to check login by `credentials` function**

inside you `LoginController` add `credentials`  function and append extra field with email, password

Example:

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->email(), 'password');
        $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'status', '1');
        return $credentials;
    }
```

Comment: Great, but how can I use it to check if email_verified_at is not null?

Answer (score 5):

please add  below code in your LoginController..

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
{

 return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['type' => 'USER']);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question tag is **laravel 5.2**, then for 5.2 you should override [getCredentials](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L154) function:

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');

    $credentials['status'] = 1;

    return $credentials;
}
```

---

if you using **laravel 5.3+** the answer of Emtiaz Zahid is correct (override [credentials](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L86) function)

Answer (score 2):

In your LoginController add an extra field in the following function

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
 return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['column-name' => 'value']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your LoginController.php

```
 Illuminate\Http\Request;

 protected function credentials(Request $request)
 {
 return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['verified' => 1]);
 }
```